# Mudblazor Select Element hidden is not working

Tags: select, properties, hidden, mudblazor

I've been trying to hide a MudSelect element under some circonstances.
However it looks like a MudSelect can't be hidden even if the parameter is valide.

```
@page "/"
    
   <MudSelect T="string" hidden="@IsShow">
      <MudSelectItem T="string">A<MudSelectItem>
      <MudSelectItem T="string">B<MudSelectItem>
   </MudSelect>
    
   <button @onclick="@Show">Show/Hide</button>
  
 @code {
       private bool IsShow   {get;set;} = false;
       private void Show()
       {
           IsShow =   !IsShow;
       }      
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either:-

1. Use the [visibility](https://mudblazor.com/utilities/visibility#basic-usage) CSS utility class.
2. Disable/Enable the component using the `Disabled` [property](https://mudblazor.com/api/select#properties).

```
<MudSelect Disabled="_disabled" Class="@(_visible?"visible":"invisible")" T="string">
    <MudSelectItem T="string" Value="@("Cappuccino")" />
    <MudSelectItem T="string" Value="@("Cafe Latte")" />
    <MudSelectItem T="string" Value="@("Espresso")" />
</MudSelect>

<MudButton OnClick="HandleVisibilityClick">Visible/Invisible</MudButton>
<MudButton OnClick="HandleDisableClick">Disable/Enable</MudButton>
@code {
    bool _disabled = false;
    bool _visible = true;
    void HandleVisibilityClick()
    {
        _visible = !_visible;
    }
    void HandleDisableClick()
    {
        _disabled=!_disabled;
    }
}
```

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wEwHuVERezOUFdTx)

Comment: Disableing is not really what I'm looking for but it may be usefull for some other cases, Giving the property throught the class is nice thought, thanks for this !

Comment: Np, yea I wanted to show that disabling is also an option, depending on use case.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the mudblazor element is bugged. Or this might be a feature.

In eather case, you can hide the element by putting it in a div and hidding the div itself.

```
@page "/"
<div hidden="@IsShow">
   <MudSelect T="string">
      <MudSelectItem T="string">A<MudSelectItem>
      <MudSelectItem T="string">B<MudSelectItem>
   </MudSelect>
</div>
   <button @onclick="@Show">Show/Hide</button>
  
 @code {
       private bool IsShow   {get;set;} = false;
       private void Show()
       {
           IsShow =   !IsShow;
       }      
 }
```